# ThreeEvent and WheelEvent not recognised in TypeScript & react-three-fiber (@react-three/fiber)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, three.js, mouseevent, react-three-fiber

I have a basic mesh box with an `onWheel` listener, and I want to pass along the mouse event data to a handler function. However, TS throws a series of different errors, and never seems to recognise `ThreeEvent` or `WheelEvent`, no matter how I try to use them.

In screenshot 1 you can see that in the `onWheel` prop TS infers that a `ThreeEvent<WheelEvent>` is the event type. Yet when I try to type the event in my handler function, I get an error saying three.js has no exported member `ThreeEvent` (screenshot 2).

I've tried importing via named imports (i.e. `import {ThreeEvent/WheelEvent} from "three";`, and also using the `THREE.ThreeEvent` syntax as used in the examples on the [react-three-fiber docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-three/fiber). Also, above this line I'm typing a `useRef` successfully like so: `const boxRef = useRef<THREE.Mesh>();`

My tsconfig is the basic one from the create-react-app template, and my versions are as follows:

```json
"dependencies": {
    "@react-three/fiber": "^7.0.19",
    "three": "^0.135.0",
    "typescript": "^4.1.2"
}
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/three": "^0.134.0"
}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should install the types for typescript.

```
npm install --save @types/three
```

Afterwards the types should be available.

You have issues with your imports, ThreeEvent must be imported from '@react-three/fiber'and WheelEvent from 'react'.

```
import { WheelEvent } from 'react';
import { ThreeEvent } from '@react-three/fiber';
```

Comment: I've already got it in my `devDependencies`, as I included above. Are you suggesting I move it to `dependencies` instead? I shouldn't need to, right?

Comment: devDependencies should be enough. Try this: import {ThreeEvent, WheelEvent} from "three"; and then instead of THREE.ThreeEvent use ThreeEvent<WheelEvent>

Comment: they also don't work, unfortunately. They both are not recognised: `Module '"three"' has no exported member 'ThreeEvent'.` Same for WheelEvent.

Comment: I updated my solution, please try to add the imports like that

Comment: It works, thank you. It was very unclear where the types were supposed to be coming from -- `WheelEvent` coming from React is something I never would have guessed.